# I'm building for Raspberry Pi and have unresolved system symbols

Tags: c++, gcc, raspberry-pi3

I'm building a library on/for the Raspberry Pi and want to know where these missing symbols are, and how I link to the appropriate libraries.

I compile with

```
G++ -pthread -x c++ -std=c++11 ... source   
// note this also with gcc same problem whether g++ or gcc command
```

And link with

```
gcc -pthread -shared -shared-libgcc ... ( objs, libs )
```

undefined symbols:

```
undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
undefined reference to `ceil'
undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_release'
undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
undefined reference to `__dynamic_cast'
undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
undefined reference to `std::string::operator=(char const*)'
undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for artd::Thread'
undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_abort'
undefined reference to `__cxa_demangle'
undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
undefined reference to `dladdr'
undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_acquire'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why not use `g++` to link as well?

Comment: I didn't because the old build script for c++ I wrote a while back used gcc and used the -stdlib=xxx argument which seems to be invalid today.  I also figured the linker would be language independent dealing with native .o modules that could have been produced by compiling one of many languages, and it was up to the "user" to put in the right libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the object files with g++ instead of GCC. The GCC does not add the required c++ libraries.

Comment: Thanks - this got rid of 5/6 of them.

Comment: the dladr one comes from libdl which was missing.